# How to paginate though a sorted table in codeigniter?

Tags: sorting, codeigniter, pagination

I'm using the default paginator to add the pae offset to uri(3) and the sort data is put in and associative array to uri like this in the table headers

```
echo anchor("/contact/index/$paging/".$this->uri->assoc_to_uri($assoc),$column);
```

at the moment i can sort desc and asc by clicking on the headers, but when i want to cycle through the pages it'll only put the page offset in uri(3) but i want to add and additional assoc into the page links.

at the moment the paginator links are made like this

```
$this->pagination->create_links();
```

but i would like to be able to add an additional assoc to each page link

```
$this->pagination->create_links($this->uri->assoc_to_uri($assoc));
```

like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to make changes to the paginator library, so i've extended it.

i've called it paginatorsortable

http://gist.github.com/649102